# bootstrap clearfix not working. Holes in layout chrome

Tags: php, loops, twitter-bootstrap-3, vue.js, clearfix

Hey guys I created my own custom cards in bootstrap 3 as I need to support rather old browsers and cant yet upgrade to bootstrap four. The cards have a video in them. a title and a button. Heres the css for the cards.

```
.card{width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px; padding: 15px; background-color: white;}
        .card video{width:100%;}
        .card-title{font-weight: bold;}
```

I than have this templates page with a simple col-md-4 layout. And I use vuejs to loop through an array I get from the database

```
<style>
    .categoryButtonSelected{background-color: #1c71b9 !important; color: white !important;}
    .headertitle{text-align: center; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
</style>
<?php
require_once('database.php');

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT t.*, GROUP_CONCAT(c.category) categories, GROUP_CONCAT(k.keyword) keywords FROM dataclayTemplates t LEFT JOIN dataclayCategoryLink cl JOIN dataclayCategories c ON cl.categoryId=c.id ON t.id=cl.templateId LEFT JOIN dataclayKeywordLink kl JOIN dataclayKeywords k ON kl.keywordId=k.id ON t.id=kl.templateId GROUP BY t.id"))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if($row["categories"] == null) {
      $row["categoryArray"] = [];
    } else {
      $row["categoryArray"] = array_unique(explode(",",$row["categories"]));
    }
    unset($row["categories"]);
    if($row["keywords"] == null) {
      $row["keywordArray"] = [];
    } else {
      $row["keywordArray"] = array_unique(explode(",",$row["keywords"]));
    }
    unset($row["keywords"]);
    $templateArray[] = $row;
  }
}

$result->close();

$categoryArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT category FROM creative_engine.dataclayCategories;"))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($categoryArray, $row['category']);
  }
}

$result->close();

$keywordArray = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT keyword FROM creative_engine.dataclayKeywords;"))
{
  while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    array_push($keywordArray, $row['keyword']);
  }
}

$result->close();

$mysqli->close();

include('header.php');

?>
 <div v-cloak id="templates" class="container">
<div class="row"><h1 class="headertitle">Creative Engine Templates</h1></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div v-cloak v-bind:key="template.itemId + '_' + index" v-for="(template, index) in searchResults" class="col-md-4">
        <div class="card">
            <video muted :src="'CreativeEngine/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.mp4'" controls preload="none" controlsList="nodownload nofullscreen" :poster="'CreativeEngine/'+template.itemId+'/'+template.thumbName+'.jpg'" loop="loop"></video>
            <div class="card-body">

                <p class="card-title">{{template.itemName}}</p><!--end card-title-->
                <p v-show="displaycount==0" class="card-text">Please create a display to customize</p><!--end user has no display card-text-->
                <p v-show="displaycount>0" class="card-text">Custom Text, Custom Colors, Upload Logo</p><!--end user has display card text-->
                <p class="card-text">{{template.renderTime}} minutes</p>
                <a href="#" v-show="loggedin==1 && displaycount>0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Customize</a><!--logged in and has display button-->
                <a href="#" v-show="loggedin==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" disabled>Customize</a><!--not logged in button-->
                 <a href="getCustomer.php?showAddDisplayForm=1" v-show="loggedin==1 && displaycount==0" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Create A Display</a>
            </div><!--end card-body-->
        </div><!--end card-->
      </div><!-- end col-md-4-->
      </div><!--end row-->

</div><!--end templates app-->
```

I've tried clearfixes and just about everything I can think of but I keep getting a whole on the sixth card in my layout like this (this is only happening on chrome while edge and firefox work fine
[Picture demenstrating problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71wLK.jpg)

If I'm doing this wrong or if anyone has any ideas let me know

Comment: The problem is because your video image height. Set common max-height for all your video image.

Comment: That works for the first breakpoint but than it screws with the others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/*Cards*/
.card{width: 100%; margin-bottom: 30px; box-shadow: 0 0 5px; padding: 15px; background-color: white;}
.card video{width:100%;}
.card-title{font-weight: bold;}

@media only screen and (max-width : 3840px) {
.card video {height: 150px;}
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 990px) {
.card video {height: auto;}
}
```

in order to fix the problem I had to put media queries in and set a height and than set it to auto once it got to a certain screen size